# Why does this C++ code give memory limit exceeded?

Tags: c++

This is the question Im trying to solve: [Link](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1003/B)

Im running this code in an online editor and it gives a memory limit exceeded, even though I have used str+=c instead of str=str+c. And I cant seem to figure out why. Could anyone help me wth this?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve(){
    int a,b,x;
    cin>>a>>b>>x;
    string res="";
    res+='0';
    a--;
    while(x--){
        cout<<res;
        res+=res.back()=='0'?'1':'0';
        if(res.back()=='0')
        a--;
        else
        b--;
    }
    string ans="";
    for(char ch: res){
        ans+=ch;
        if(ch=='0'){
            while (a--){
                ans+='0';
            }
        }
        else{
            while(b--){
                ans+='1';
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<ans;


}
int main() {
    int t;
    t=1;
    while(t--){
        solve();
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

The input I give is 3 3 3
and output I expect is 101100

Comment: Use a debugger!

Comment: Your loops have a serious problem.  You do stuff like `while(a--)` (and same for `b`).  Now, that will work if the loop is only run once, but if you ever execute the loop again, `a` is going to be -1 and `a--` will keep getting more negative while the loop condition remains true.  You're pushing tons of data onto `ans` because of this, and waiting for the value to wrap around all the way back to zero (which is undefined behavior for signed integers anyway).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] without relying on external links. What is the code supposed to do, what is the input, what is the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your solution idea is nearly correct.

The most important requirement here is the number of tansitions. So, when we go from a 1 to a 0 or from a 0 to a 1. These transitions must exist. And the number of transisitions also determines the minimum numbers of 0es or 1s needed.

If more 0es or 1s should be present, then you can simply repeat any 0 or 1 with the same value. This will have no impact on the transistion.

Let's have a closer look. Below is an example for the minimum number of 0es or 1s for a given number of transitions

```
Transitions   Sequence        Min 0es   Min 1s
1             01              1         1
2             010             2         1
3             0101            2         2
4             01010           3         2
5             010101          3         3
6             0101010         4         3
```

You immediately see that there is a simple mathematical relation between the number of transitions and the minimum number of needed 1s or 0es. It is:

- (Number of Transitions + 1)/2 rounded up
- (Number of Transitions + 1)/2 rounded down

For odd number of transisitions, the minimum numbers of 1s or 0es are always the same. For even numbers of transitions however, it depends on the starting value.

The reverse conclusion is that it does not matter for odd transitions, if you start with a 0 or a 1. For an even number of transitions it is important.

Example:

Input 1 2 2, meaning one 0, two 1s and 2 transitions.

With the above formula, we calculate that we need two digits of the one and 2 digits for the other, so theoretically `010` or `101`, But since we shall use only one 0, it can only be `101`

Resulting in: If we have an even number of transitions, then the start value may depend from other input parameters. And more precicely: If the minimum number needed for a digit is equal to the given number for that digit, then we must start with the other digit.

Example:

- 1 2 2 must be 101
- 2 2 2 can be 0110 or 1001

Knowing that we can now draft an algorithm. We will work only one one of the many solutions.

1. Check, if the number of transitions is odd or even
2. If even, then determine the start digit with above condition
3. create a sequence of 010101... or 10101... depending on the start digit and the given number of sequences
4. Add the not yet consumed 0es or 1s to the sequence by simply duplicating or repeating existing 0es or ones.

This can then be implemented in a similar way like your approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    // Here we will store the input parameters
    int numberOfZeroes{}, numberOfOnes{}, numberOfTransitions{};

    // The input will always be correct, so need to check it
    std::cin >> numberOfZeroes >> numberOfOnes >> numberOfTransitions;

    // Start digit
    char digit{ '0' };

    // Check, if the number of transitions is even, then we need a special additional check
    if (numberOfTransitions % 2 == 0) {

        // Calculate the minimum number of needed 0es or 1s
        const int minimum = (numberOfTransitions + 1) / 2;

        // Check, if we need to start with digit 1
        if (minimum == numberOfZeroes)
            digit = '1';
    }
    // Now we want to create a string starting made of alternating 0es and 1s, so transitions
    std::string sequenceWithTransitions{};

    do {
        // Build string
        sequenceWithTransitions += digit;

        // Update counters and digits
        if (digit == '1') {
            digit = '0';      // Make transition
            --numberOfOnes;   // Update counter
        }
        else {
            digit = '1';      // Make transition
            --numberOfZeroes; // Update counter
        }
    } while (numberOfTransitions--);

    // Fill in the remaining 0es and 1s
    std::string result{};
    for (char c : sequenceWithTransitions) {

        result += c;          // Copy value

        if (c == '1')         // Potential replications of 1
            while (numberOfOnes-- > 0)
                result += '1';
        if (c == '0')         // Potential replications of 0
            while (numberOfZeroes-- > 0)
                result += '0';
    }
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

Of course this code can be optimzied in many ways